# Would anyone support a feature request to give users a "no comments" option when posting a question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, comments, etiquette

Who would support this idea of a "comments off" toggle on your own questions when you post a question? Requests for clarification would be submitted, and publicly displayed after approval - but not as a comment.

I don't feel like I need to quote the Stack Exchange model which indicates this is a site for asking, answering, and editing. I'm new so maybe it's more evident to me, but I *have* noticed that (particularly on certain Stack sites) there is a trend towards people trolling in the comments or giving answers in comments without clicking "answer", presumably because answers risk reputation change up or down. The Stack model says that the focus of the site is not reputation, that is just how the community thanks you. I do personally use the comments so it's not like I'm anti-comment, but I try not to abuse the comments. I also feel like it's nice to be recognized so I'm not against reputation, I just think this would just be a safeguard for when you are posting in forums which are more prone to "leniency".

Again, Who would support this idea of a "comments off" toggle on your own questions when you post a question? How can we get this feature added?

Comment: Request for clarification: how would users request clarification like I'm doing right now?

Comment: however it suits you best VLAZ. Answers. Comments. Telepathy. The floor is yours.

Answer (score 11):

### Comment Locks

Moderators have the ability to prevent comments on any post. It's a great tool for some situations (such as when an argument in the comments is forming or has already broken out). However, from experience, it can also be disruptive:

- No explanation for downvotes/close votes. In fact, no feedback whatsoever. Comments are often the only viable way to get a post improved, since edits can often only be used when the original post is clear and the edit is changing something that's not too big (and would conflict with the author's intent) and not too small (low rep users must change 6 characters in a suggested edit). Answers are not for commenting
- No linking related posts
- Prevents review from working ([Should a comment lock invalidate a reopen review?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377293/323179))
- Users find it confusing and frustrating when used on a new post

Due to the potential for abuse (namely for a user to try to prevent any criticism on their post), it's not something that should be given to everyone. I don't even really see a need for non-moderators to have it.

### Your alternatives

As a regular user, you have two ways to help keep comments from getting out of control:

1. You can flag for a comment lock ("in need of moderator attention"). Most mods will only give you one if the comments look like they're going off the rails. Very rarely might a moderator use a lock because the question is on a controversial subject that tends to generate arguments (e.g. erotica). It's worth noting that moderators are already notified automatically when a post gets too chatty (i.e. 20 comments).
2. You can flag comments for removal. All users can do this under their own posts, but users with less than 15 rep would probably need to flag as "something else" and explain.